# Is $(-1)^{\infty}$ an indeterminate form?

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

We know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n=(-1)^{\infty}$ doesn't exist. Now take $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{2n}=(-1)^{\infty}$. This limit exists, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}((-1)^2)^n=1$. Does this mean that $(-1)^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure because it wasn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: (-1)^n=±1 for any integer according to the parity. If you know that   ∞ is odd or even, you can calculate (-1)^∞.

Comment: I wouldn't think of considering parity of $\infty$. That's interesting

Comment: Has nothing to do with the "parity" of $\infty$, just picture $(-1)^{1/2}$, is not even defined. That is more a problem in the definition of the function than an indetermination.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily because the concept "indeterminate form" does not have a widely accepted formal definition; in many books this is simply presented as a list of examples.  Your example is not in that list, so in those books, it would not be an "indeterminate form".  However, if you try to write a definition that is not merely a list, then your example likely could be an indeterminate form, depending of course on how the definition is written.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose so ... even $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, and you are just adding a question about the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe over the integers, but over the reals - which is what's more often meant when people talk about indeterminate forms - it'll always either diverge or go to zero, since for values where the base is sufficiently close to $-1$, further approaching the limit enough to increase the exponent by $1$ (which you can always do since the exponent approaches infinity) will reverse the sign.  So is that an indeterminate form?  I'd say no.